# Perfect square equation $12\alpha^2\cdot x^3+12\alpha\cdot x^2+12\alpha\left(1-\alpha\right)\cdot x+\left(2-3\alpha\right)^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, square-numbers

Well, I have the following function:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right):=12\alpha^2\cdot x^3+12\alpha\cdot x^2+12\alpha\left(1-\alpha\right)\cdot x+\left(2-3\alpha\right)^2\tag1$$

Where $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$.

> Question: I want to find $x$ such that $\text{y}\left(x\right)$ can be written as a perfect square. I already know that when $x=3\alpha^2-2$, we can write:
>
> $$\text{y}\left(x\right)=\left[2+3\alpha\left(6\alpha\left(\alpha^2-1\right)+1\right)\right]^2\tag2$$
>
> But I want to find other solutions for $x$.

Comment: Is it fair to ask:  What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: A simpler solution is $x=0$, which you haven't considered yet.

Comment: Similarly, $x=-1$ and $x=\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}$ yields a perfect square.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I believe the second one should be $\,x=\frac{a-1}{a}\,$. Also, $\,x=1\,$ and $\,x = -2/3\,$.

Comment: One of solutions is $x=\frac{(-1+\alpha)(27\alpha^6+27\alpha^5-27\alpha^4-36\alpha^3+9\alpha^2+15\alpha-4)(9\alpha^4-6\alpha^2+3\alpha-1)}{\alpha(2+3\alpha-18\alpha^2+18\alpha^4)^2}$

Comment: "*find $x$ such that $\text{y}\left(x\right)$ can be written as a perfect square*" $\;-\;$ May be worth clarifying whether you mean finding a polynomial (or a function of some other type) $\,x(a)\,$ such that $\,y\big(x(a)\big)\,$ is the square of a polynomial (or some other type of function) in $\,a\,$ vs. finding values of $\,x \in \mathbb Z\,$ such that $\,y(x)\,$ is an integer square. The comments thus far seem to assume the former, but the question as written (and the tags) could technically mean either.